# Create multiple users, to have all privileges on each others relations/objects

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgresql-12

I'm logged with postgres user (BTW, this is not superuser, DB is hosted on google cloud).

I need that create multiple users, and all that users to be have  access on each  other's objects

So, with postgres user I created 2 users like:

```
CREATE USER postgres_subuser1  PASSWORD 'some_password';
GRANT postgres TO postgres_subuser1;

CREATE USER postgres_subuser2  PASSWORD 'some_password';
GRANT postgres TO postgres_subuser2;
```

Then I logged with "postgres_subuser1" and crated table `table1`

Then I logged with "postgres_subuser2", and tried insert into `table1`, but error

`permission denied for table table1` appears

This even happens when I try to insert with "postgres" user, only table owner "postgres_subuser1" can insert into table.

Question: how can I manage like so, that all users created by current user, have all privileges on each others objects?

Comment: You want to set [default privileges on each other's created objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

Comment: @Bergi -         Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [alter the default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) for objects created by these users to grant each other access:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres_subuser1 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO postgres_subuser2;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE postgres_subuser2 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO postgres_subuser1;
```

Also I think you have the `GRANT postgres TO postgres_subuser2;` backwards, surely you meant giving the `postgres` user the permission to change into the `postgres_subuser2` role, not the other way round?

Comment: Thank you, but this still gives same result,I just created 2 new users, (to be fresh everything)
Then I   did `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES .. ` as you mentioned, for both of them

Comment: Though, table created by first user, is still not denied for second user

Comment: What do you mean by "still not denied"? It should be granted, no?

Comment: @ohno Did you run the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES …` before creating the tables? What do the privileges of the table look like now?

Comment: What do you mean by "still not denied"? -- after `ALTER DEFAULT ..` for  both users, I logged in with first user and created table `table1`, then I logged with  second user and tried: `select count(*) from table1`

Comment: It shows error: `permission denied for table table1`

Comment: Of course, it gives result (0) if I try same query with table owner (first user)

Comment: "Did you run the ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES" Yes,  …" before creating the tables?" - Yes. "What do the privileges of the table look like now" There are privileges only for fisr user on this table, no single privilege for second user. I checked using query:

Comment: `SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM   information_schema.table_privileges 
WHERE  grantee IN('postgres_subuser1', 'postgres_subuser2')`

Comment: "still not denied" should have read "still denied" or "still not granted" I guess, just a typo in your comment. Hm, that really should have worked. What happens when you try to grant the privileges directly using the `postgres` user, can he even grant them? You said your `postgres` is not a superuser, but notice that "*you can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.*"

Comment: Yes, "still not granted". I created both users using "postgres" user and I  tried run "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES ... GRANT .. " from  "postgres" user too

Comment: Now I tested the same Thing, on my local DB instance, where "postgres" is SUPERUSER, though exactly same result

Comment: Thank you very much, for your time and attempt to help